# Typescript cant find class CI only

Tags: typescript, bitbucket, pipeline, ecmascript-5, bitbucket-pipelines

I have an **Angular** project and when I run "ng test" locally everything works just fine, however in bitbucket pipelines I have this error.

> ERROR in src/app/services/user-store/user.service.ts:7:22 - error
> TS2307: Cannot find module '../../models/user' or its corresponding
> type declarations. 7 import { User } from '../../models/user';

**My tsconfig.base**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**My tsconfig.spec.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I think is related with the "target" in my tsconfig.base, but i'm not sure, maybe something missing in my yaml?

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
pipelines:
 default:
   - step:
       name: Build, Lint and Test
       image: rastasheep/alpine-node-chromium:12-alpine
       caches:
         - node
       deployment: test
       script:
         - npm install 
         - npm run test:ci
         - npm run e2e:ci
         - npm run build:prod
         - pipe: atlassian/firebase-deploy:0.3.0
           variables:
             FIREBASE_TOKEN: '$FIREBASE_TOKEN_CI'
```

**User.ts**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export interface User{
    uid: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}
```

Comment: Make sure your working directory is correct and that your npm scripts don't invoke any globally installed packages.

Comment: Also check file name(case), when working on windows, files names are case in-sensitive, on linux image, those will be case sensitive.

Comment: Have you found the solution ? I am struggeling with the same issue